# Keycloak realm login using postman

Tags: java, microservices, keycloak, ibm-api-management, keycloak-rest-api

I have app1 which has section or menu of api management. app1 has separate login and does not use keycloak. Now api management option is nothing but the [apiman](https://www.apiman.io/) which uses keycloak for authentication and authorization. I dont want to login twice to get into apiman so I am registering user to keycloak(apiman) from app1's user master module(I am able to do that and also able to login manually).
Now I want to automate this process so that once a user is logged in app1 and clicks on api management option/menu it will authenticate/authorize user with one java microservice and then directly move into apiman dashboard. Is it at all possible to bypass keycloak login using java program ? Is there any way to do that?

I have tried following thing:

POST

https://{HOST:PORT}/auth/realms/apiman/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=apimanui&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}?session_state=a2a53973-12ad-4011-b202-b6c7bc538287&state=d5a41eb1-00ce-4932-b910-241df8db5159&login=true&scope=openid

[image]

Comment: I am also facing this issue, How to login with API for Keycloak SAML (Not open-id)